# Inno Setup doesn't allow access to all registry keys, why?

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I use this code to know if a key exists or not:

```pascal
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Autodesk') then
begin
  MsgBox('Key exists!!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

for this example, it works, I have the message box, but with this it doesn't:

```pascal
if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Autodesk\Maya') then
begin
  MsgBox('Key exists!!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

But the `Maya` key exists on my computer. Can anybody help me?

EDIT :

In fact, it seems that Inno Setup don't access to the right keys...
For example, with this code I list all the subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`, but (!) the result is all subkey of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` ...

```pascal
if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE', Names) then
begin
  S := '';
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names)-1 do
    S := S + Names[I] + #13#10;
  MsgBox('List of subkeys:'#13#10#13#10 + S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Why this `Wow6432Node` key?

Answer (score 23):

It's not Inno Setup's fault at all; [the Registry is virtualized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization) in Vista and higher, and on 64-bit there are [branches for native 64-bit and WOW'ed 32-bit](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internals-and-architecture/what-s-the-wow6432node-under-the-hkey_local_machine-software-registry-subkey-.aspx).

In this case, since Inno Setup is a 32-bit program, the OS directs all of its `HKLM\Software` registry requests to the `WOW6432Node`.

To handle the registry virtualization in your installer, you can specifically use x86 and x64 key roots. For example, use `HKLM32` or `HKLM64` in your `[Registry]` section when you need to differentiate. In `[Code]` section, wrap registry helper function calls using `HKLM64` in an `if IsWin64` block.

This example works ok from our installer, whether or not the installer is declared as an x64 installer.

```pascal
function Mobu120x64IsAvailable(): Boolean;
var
  resultString: String;
begin
  resultString := 'No';
  if IsWin64 then
  begin
    Result := RegValueExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\MotionBuilder\2012', 'InstallPath');
    if Result then begin
      resultString := 'Yes';
    end;
    Log('Win64: Found Mobu 12.0 for x64?:' + resultString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The key sentence there: "The values may have a suffix of 32 or 64. Root key values with a suffix of 32 (for example, HKLM32) map to the 32-bit view of the registry; root key values with a suffix of 64 (for example, HKLM64) map to the 64-bit view of the registry."

Answer (score 18):

Let me guess... you're on Windows 7 64-bit?

It's not InnoSetup's fault at all, it's that [the Registry is virtualized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28VS.85%29.aspx) in Vista & higher, and on 64-bit there are [branches for native 64-bit and WOW'ed 32-bit](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internals-and-architecture/what-s-the-wow6432node-under-the-hkey_local_machine-software-registry-subkey-.aspx).

In this case, since InnoSetup is a 32-bit program, the OS directs all of its HKLM\Software Registry requests to the WOW6432Node.

If your program is 64-bit, then you want to use a 64-bit setup program too.

Comment: Yes thank you it's my problem ! But i need to make an installer that works on 32 and 64bits. It's just a plugin for Maya (3D Software) independant of architecture. But Maya can be 32 or 64bits and i need to know that for copying my files in the right folder. If i use a x64 installer, it won't work on x86, but i doesn't want to make 2 installers. a solution to bypass the WOW6432Node link without making a x64 installer ?

Comment: Hmm... I've never had to build an x64 package with InnoSetup myself. But the help docs include several references on [32- vs 64-bit](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) and [limitations of 64-bit installs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=64bitlimitations) that help clarify what is effected by redirection and what isn't. But first you probably need to enable 64-bit mode by setting [ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode to "x64"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode)...

Comment: @ewall: I recommend putting those Inno help links in your actual answer rather than just the comments.

Comment: Unless you've written a 64-bit plug-in, you *don't* need a 64-bit installer, @John. A 64-bit program (such as Maya) cannot use 32-bit plug-ins, so it's OK if your 32-bit installer cannot detect the presence of 64-bit Maya — the thing you're installing wouldn't work there anyway.

Comment: I just had this problem with motion builder 2012 x64. If I do:
`[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64`
it finds the keys ok, but then the x86 keys it needs to find are not found. The documentation for EnableFsRedirection include a sample to flip the mode back temporarily to x86 mode. You can't enable x64 mode using the example code if you didn't start in an x64 mode.

Comment: The EnableFsRedirection doesn't enable registry redirection though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `Software\Autodesk\Maya` is a registry key? Maybe it's just a value and you have to use `RegValueExists`.

Comment: Yes it's a key, and I can't access all of it's subkeys too.