# How to programatically change BDE 'INIT' settings

Tags: registry, bde

In Inno setup, I set SHAREDMEMLOCATION and SHAREDMEMSIZE as a registry key for BDE

```
; BDE Memory Hacks
Root:HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SHAREDMEMLOCATION"; ValueData: "0x5000";
Root:HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SHAREDMEMSIZE"; ValueData: "4096";
```

I'm assuming there's either something I don't know about how BDE works or how the windows registry works. I've found some info to which I'm supposed to do BDE stuff through the BDE api but I can't seem to find a lot of info/libraries to do that.

Comment: I thought I could set the registry key manually, but it looks like I couldn't. Edited question to focus on BDE/registry.

Answer (score 0):

The place for the SHAREDMEMLOCATION and SHAREDMEMSIZE registry values, in a non-virtualized registry, should be **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland\Database Engine\Settings\SYSTEM\INIT`**.

Does your InnoSetup script work, if you remove the "Wow6432Node" part?

See 
[Inno-Setup doesn't allow access to all registry keys, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033976/inno-setup-doesnt-allow-access-to-all-registry-keys-why)

And "Registry Virtualization" on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx

You should be able to set the registry values from your BDE application, the settings just go to a Wow6432Node thingy if UAC is turned on.