# Get Notepad++ installation directory in InnoSetup

Tags: registry, notepad++, inno-setup

This stupid problem is driving me crazy: I'm trying to retrieve Notepad++ installation directory fro the registry by reading the default value of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Notepad++` (which is `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`).

I tried different methods, which all work on *other* keys, but *not* with Notepad++. All of the following methods work with all keys I tried *but* Notepad++:

```
// Using RegQueryStringValue
var
  Mess: String;
...
If RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.avast.nativeproxy', '', Mess) Then
  MsgBox('Retrieved: '+Mess, mbInformation, MB_OK)
Else
  MsgBox('Wala', mbError, MB_OK);
```

```
// Using registry constants
MsgBox('Your NPP: '+ExpandConstant('{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.avast.nativeproxy,}), mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

Whenever I replace `SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.avast.nativeproxy` with `SOFTWARE\Notepad++`, I get an empty string (or `RegQueryStringValue()` returns false).

I thought the `++` could cause problems so I also tried to double them, escape them with `'Notepad'+#43+#43` or `'Notepad%43%43'` but nothing is working.

Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: See [@Epu's answer to Inno Setup doesn't allow access to all registry keys, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033976/850848#6333463)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I voted to close my own question as a duplicate of the one you indicated, as it was indeed the same problem: using ` HKML64` instead of `HKLM` solved it. Thanks again!

Comment: Though make sure you use `HKLM64` on 64-bit machines only. On 32-bit machines, use `HKLM32`.